# Migrating .DBF files to Firebird 2.5: how create a query with UNION of different DBRMS

Tags: firebird, dbf

I want to transfer many tables from .DBF files (old DbIV) to Firebird; I utilize ZEOS components to Firebird connections and the transfer is simple: it is enough to replace the preceding queries with the new Zeos components.

But a large number of queries contain UNION and JOIN clauses, and the .DBF tables now are in different DBRMS. I know that is not possible for Firebird to join tables that "resides" in different databases (.fdb), but I must find a solution to join the same FB tables previously joined with .DBF files.

Do you have any suggestion as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: DBF is ISAM format, just like CSV, MS Excel, etc. There is no SQL in the DBF. So when you say "query contains UNION and JOIN clauses" and "the .DBF tables now are in different DBRMS" - you mean some extra SQL service built ON TOP of the DBF files, like Advantage or something. The very DBF tables do not have any SQL in them. Consequently, you can just totally copy all the DBF tables into Firebird temporary tables and then after that do all your queries within one Firebird database

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with _"different DBRMS"_?

Comment: I clear the situation. Names.DBF contains names of persons; NameCom.DBF contains names of municipalities. The tables are single file and are menaged with the Delphy 7 BDE components TQuery (which contains a SQL property) and TTable. One TQuery containes for example "SELECT * FROM NAMES.DBF INNER JOIN NAMECOM.DBF ON...". Now the table Names.dbf is in the firebird PROC.FDB and the table NameCom.dbf in COMMONS.FDB. I hope to be explained me.